# Can't deploy todos; Failed to remove container (todos-frontend)

Tags: javascript, linux, meteor, meteorite, meteor-up

First time with linux and meteor up, so sorry if there's a stupid mistake. I try to deploy the meteor example app todos with mupx, and followed the instructions from the readme, but I'm getting the following mistake. (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server ). Thanks for help.

```
Configuration file : mup.json
Settings file : settings.json

“ Checkout Kadira!
It's the best way to monitor performance of your app.
Visit: https://kadira.io/mup ”

Meteor app path : /home/jan/todos
Using buildOptions : {}
Currently, it is only possible to build iOS apps on an OS X system.

Started TaskList: Deploy app 'todos' (linux)
[h2544161.stratoserver.net] - Uploading bundle
[h2544161.stratoserver.net] - Uploading bundle: SUCCESS
[h2544161.stratoserver.net] - Sending environment variables
[h2544161.stratoserver.net] - Sending environment variables: SUCCESS
[h2544161.stratoserver.net] - Initializing start script
[h2544161.stratoserver.net] - Initializing start script: SUCCESS
[h2544161.stratoserver.net] - Invoking deployment process
Invoking deployment process: FAILED
-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
Failed to remove container (todos-frontend): Error response from daemon: No such container: todos-frontend
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint todos on network bridge: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use.
-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
todos
base: Pulling from meteorhacks/meteord
518dc1482465: Already exists
a3ed95caeb02: Already exists
a3ed95caeb02: Already exists
a3ed95caeb02: Already exists
537c534356b6: Already exists
b65a0e1e554b: Already exists
a3ed95caeb02: Already exists
a3ed95caeb02: Already exists
Digest: sha256:b5a4f6efa98e4070792ed36d33b14385a28e6ceda691a492ee5b9f2431b1515a
Status: Image is up to date for meteorhacks/meteord:base
d6d192579495851d5817288ff89abb69512562d7c2a7075f965484e64583c61b
```

Comment: this is kinda not a good question, because you only tell us that you have a problem, but we can't help with just that. You should see why your `todos-frontend` is giving you problem, since he says there's "no such container".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Failed to remove container (todos-frontend): Error response from daemon: No such container: todos-frontend
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint todos on network bridge: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated.*

Just had the same issue,

finally deployed after changing file port number to an unused port in my-deployment mup.json somehow docker service could release ports automatically when it wants. I've used 80, 8000, 8001 so far but I haven't successfully deployed to the same port twice, but reading

credit to [this](http://code.krister.ee/mupx-problems/)

## It seems that different deployments may conflict each other pretty easily. I have no resolution for this.